# Green and heaviside function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, greens-function

I have a question concerning the [Wikipedia's article on green function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) stating in the section "table of green fuctions", that a green function satisfying:
$$(\gamma+\partial_t)G(t)=\delta(t)$$
has an explicit form of 
$$G(t)=\Theta(t)e^{-\gamma t}$$
where $\Theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

My question concerns a proof of this fact, since the direct insertion yields
$$\gamma\Theta(t)e^{-\gamma t}-\gamma\Theta(t)e^{-\gamma t}+\delta(t)e^{-\gamma t}=\delta(t)e^{-\gamma t}\neq\delta(t)$$
Using the fact, that $d_t \Theta(t)=\delta(t)$.

Is there an error in this procedure? What is the correct procedure to prove this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only to complement Artem's correct answer:**

Better writing $(\gamma+\partial_t)G(t)=\delta$. Now let $\psi(t)= e^{-\gamma t}$. By **definition** of product of a distribution by a smooth function (in the case of delta in fact only required to be continuous),
$$
\langle \psi\delta,\phi\rangle=\langle \delta ,\psi\phi\rangle=(\psi\phi)(0)=\phi(0)=\langle\delta,\phi\rangle.
$$

Comment: Just upvoted Jonas' answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\delta(t)f(t)=\delta(t)f(0).
$$

Comment: Well yes, but that would mean we want to apply the delta to the exponential function which we don't. We want to wait with the delta to some test function to apply there, not to some exponential. Because if we applied the delta right away, we would lose the delta and get a number and then when we applied some test function, we would get a number times a test function, not a delta applied to a test function, two different things.

Comment: It is exactly the same, this can be proved by using the usual definition of delta-function. The expression $\delta(t)f(t)$ is *not* delta-function applied to $f$, it is a distributional product, which is defined only for infinitely differentiable functions.

Comment: Correction, no, actually no. $\int \delta(t)f(t)dt=f(0)$ or in a sense of distributions $\delta_t f(t)=f(0)\neq \delta_t f(0)$

Comment: Distributional product, what is that? Such a thing does not exist.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? :)

Comment: Yes, it exists. The product of a distribution $g$ with infinetely differentiable function $f$ is defined as $\langle fg,\phi\rangle=\langle g,f\phi\rangle$ for any test function.

Comment: What does mean distribution product? As far as I know, a product of two distribution makes no sense. Plus, a dirac delta is not an infinitely differentiable function.

Comment: Dear @user74200 Two minutes ago you claimed that such thing does not exist. Now you are asking for an explanation. I am a little lost here.

Comment: So a product of a distribution and a function, not distributional product(product of two distributions), defining a product of two distributions does not make a complete sense.

Comment: Dear @user74200 you can apply your own terminology if you wish. I used more or less standard one.

Comment: Maybe for tempered distributions? But $e^{-\gamma t}$ is not a tempered distribution. But yeah, my bad, this makes sense, my bad.

Comment: Just upvoted Artem's answer.